# Accessing information in [AnyHashable : Any] as NSDictionary

Tags: ios

I am in the process of converting my code from Objective C to Swift. I have a code the calls an objective C method from a swift method. The obj C method returns an NSDictionary. Apparently Swift see this object as a type `[AnyHashable : Any]`. How do I read the information for this type? For example for a NSDictionary I would say `NSString *s = [dict objectForKey:"key"]`. What do I call in Swift to access the value in type `[AnyHashable : Any]`?

Thanks

Comment: I would think the Swift equivalent of NSDictionary would be `[AnyHashable : AnyObject]` rather than  `[AnyHashable : Any]`

Answer (score 4):

try to use code below to unwrap your result:

```
if let dict = dict as NSDictionary? as! [String:Any]? {
  print(dict[key])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding AnyHashable, if you'll look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyhashable) they give an example:

```
let descriptions: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
    AnyHashable(""): "emoji",
    AnyHashable(42): "an Int",
    AnyHashable(Int8(43)): "an Int8",
    AnyHashable(Set(["a", "b"])): "a set of strings"
]
print(descriptions[AnyHashable(42)]!)      // prints "an Int"
```

In my case I was parsing the response headers from a website so I had a key which was a string and the value was another JSON object.

The solution was straightforward, using the above syntax to obtain the entire object and cast it to string and use `JSONSerialization` to map it to a `[String : Any]` type:

```
if let jsonString = payload[AnyHashable("Key")] as? String,
   let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
   do {
       if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String : Any] {
           // json is now a [String : Any] type
   }
       else {
              print("JSON is invalid")
       }
      }
    catch {
           print("Exception converting: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscripts as in Objective-C.

Swift:

```
let s = dict["key"]
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *s = dict["key"] //is equivalent to [dict objectForKey:"key"]
```

Comment: Actually `id s = dict["key"] would be closer, since `id` is the anonymous object pointer in Objective-C.

Comment: I've tried that. I get a compiler error that reads Type '() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!' has no subscript members

Comment: I solved it. Turns out the objective C method I was calling to pass back the NSDictionary was let dict = object.getDict. I needed to say let dict = object.getDict(). Include the parens. The compiler error was not very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this:

```
let strShareLink = dict["key"] as! String
```

in swift

Hope, others will get help from this